# Orika Mapping to JAXBElement<>

Tags: java, jaxb, orika, data-mapping

I am using JAXB to generate POJOs from XSDs. Due to some reasons , the generated POJOs have `JAXBElement<CustomObject>` as property.

```
public class ResponsePackageType{

   protected JAXBElement<? extends ResponseType> response;
   ....
}
```

Multiple classes is extending `ResponseType` but I am only interested to map one type of it, and Orika is having problem recognizing this property.

My code:

```
JAXBElement<ResponsePackageType> feed = (JAXBElement<ResponsePackageType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream( "input.xml" ));

MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

Type<JAXBElement<ResponsePackageType>> respPackageType = new TypeBuilder<JAXBElement<ResponsePackageType>>(){}.build();

Type<JAXBElement<SpecialResponseType>> spRespType = new TypeBuilder<JAXBElement<SpecialResponseType>>(){}.build();

mapperFactory.classMap(respPackageType, respPackageType)
        .fieldMap("response", "response")
        .aElementType(spRespType )
        .bElementType(spRespType )
        .add()
        .byDefault().register();

MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

mapper.map(feed, objectFactory.createResponsePackage(null));
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at ma.glasnost.orika.constructor.ConstructorParameterResolver.getProperties(ConstructorParameterResolver.java:73)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.constructor.ConstructorParameterResolver.getPossibleConstructorParams(ConstructorParameterResolver.java:119)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.property.PropertyResolver.resolveConstructorProperty(PropertyResolver.java:701)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.property.PropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertyResolver.java:686)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.property.PropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertyResolver.java:616)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder.resolveProperty(ClassMapBuilder.java:828)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder.resolvePropertyForA(ClassMapBuilder.java:838)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder.fieldMap(ClassMapBuilder.java:379)
```

How do I go about to solve this issue ?? Should I use propertyResolverStrategy ?